# При сборке проекта Android Studio ругается что не может найти public setters от val-ов объекта. Хотя у val-a сеттеров быть не должно

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, setter

При сборке проекта Android Studio ругается что не может найти setters от val-ов объекта. Хотя у val-a сеттеров быть не может. Я специально ставил val потому что эти значения у объектов меняться не будут, и менять на var мне кажется нерелевантным решением.
Пытаюсь понять, почему андроид упорно требует public setters и не может запустить проект. Буду благодарен за помощь.
(В другом проекте у меня также стояли val значения у объектов в данных, и такой проблемы не было, но в чем принципиальная разница в проектах тоже не нашел, почему там все запускалось а тут он ищет setters.)

Объект:

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
@Parcelize
data class Word(
    val native: String,
    val foreign: String,
    val category: Int,
    val shown: Boolean = true,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0
) : Parcelable {
}
```

Что пишет gradle (ошибка):

```
error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class Word implements android.os.Parcelable {
         ^
Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
/*bla bla bla*/
error: Cannot find setter for field.
private final java.lang.String foreign = null;
error: Cannot find setter for field.
private final int category = 0;
\error: Cannot find setter for field.
private final boolean shown = false;
error: Cannot find setter for field.
private final int id = 0;
```

Comment: А самая первая строчка в тексте ошибки вам что-нибудь говорит?

Comment: Я не делал для паблик констрактор для объекта где все значения - val , и в других проектах все было нормально.

Comment: Room не находит конструктор под конкретный набор полей. Я не вижу упоминания о `native` в описании ошибки. А он обязателен, без него нет конструктора.

Comment: спасибо, вы навели меня на путь истинный. Поменял на nativ и все собралось. Видимо потому что в джаве есть свой термин native - среда принимала мой native за свой из коробки, и искала конструктор без свойства native.